# How might various conductive mast mounting configurations affect an electrically isolated rhombic antenna?

Tags: antenna, antenna-theory

Assuming a rhombic antenna is:

- terminated for directionality
- electrically isolated at its mount point
- mounted to a metal mast partway up vs top of mast
- horizontally oriented (elements parallel to ground)

… how might the mast affect its radiation pattern?

Is it better to mount with the mast through the rhombus or at its feed end?

Since the mast is outside the plane of polarization, I’d imagine it behaves the same as a horizontal Yagi if end-mounted (let’s ignore structural support for now).

Also, while I’m aware you can electrically steer elevation (so articles say), what if for simplicity I did this simply by physically orienting the antenna to the desired elevation? Would I run into trouble as the elevation increased (ie, closer to parallel with the mast), assuming the mast extends far enough “up” the antenna to be a nearby, in-plane conductor?

I realize this could all be modeled but I have zero experience with modeling tools and hoped some of this was known and at least some could be reasoned about.